# Jenkins is unable to find the java file in workspace

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, maven, jenkins

We are following the instructions given by some tutorials to integrate our project with jenkins unsuccessfully, we think the reason is the path to the scripts of java. Could you give us a hand?  The log result is:

```
Started by user admin

Running as SYSTEM Building in workspace C:\Users\xxxxxxx\.jenkins\workspace\JenkinsDemo Parsing POMs Established TCP socket on 57342 [JenkinsDemo] $ "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.11/bin/java" -cp C:\Users\xxxxxxx\.jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven35-agent-1.13.jar;C:\Users\xxxxxxx\apache-maven-3.8.1\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.6.0.jar;C:\Users\xxxxxxx\apache-maven-3.8.1/conf/logging jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven35Main C:\Users\xxxxxxx\apache-maven-3.8.1 C:\Users\xxxxxxx\.jenkins\war\WEB-INF\lib\remoting-4.12.jar C:\Users\xxxxxxx\.jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven35-interceptor-1.13.jar C:\Users\xxxxxxx\.jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven3-interceptor-commons-1.13.jar 57342 <===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started Executing Maven:  -B -f C:\Users\xxxxxxx\.jenkins\workspace\JenkinsDemo\pom.xml install [INFO] Scanning for projects... [INFO]  [INFO]
----------------------< JenkinsDemo:JenkinsDemo >----------------------- [INFO] Building JenkinsDemo 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT [INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]--------------------------------- [INFO]  [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ JenkinsDemo
--- [WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent! [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\xxxxxxx\.jenkins\workspace\JenkinsDemo\src\main\resources [INFO]  [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ JenkinsDemo --- [INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date [INFO]  [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ JenkinsDemo --- [WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent! [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\xxxxxxx\.jenkins\workspace\JenkinsDemo\src\test\resources [INFO]  [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ JenkinsDemo --- [INFO] No sources to compile [INFO]  [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ JenkinsDemo --- [INFO] No tests to run. [JENKINS] Guardando informes de test [INFO]  [INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ JenkinsDemo --- [INFO]  [INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ JenkinsDemo --- [INFO] Installing C:\Users\xxxxxxx\.jenkins\workspace\JenkinsDemo\target\JenkinsDemo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to C:\Users\xxxxxxx\.m2\repository\JenkinsDemo\JenkinsDemo\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\JenkinsDemo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar [INFO] Installing C:\Users\xxxxxxx\.jenkins\workspace\JenkinsDemo\pom.xml to C:\Users\xxxxxxx\.m2\repository\JenkinsDemo\JenkinsDemo\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\JenkinsDemo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom [INFO]
------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS [INFO]
------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time:  3.337 s [INFO] Finished at: 2022-05-09T12:20:50+02:00 [INFO]
------------------------------------------------------------------------ Esperando a que Jenkins finalice de recopilar datos [JENKINS] Archiving C:\Users\xxxxxxx\.jenkins\workspace\JenkinsDemo\pom.xml to JenkinsDemo/JenkinsDemo/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/JenkinsDemo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom [JENKINS] Archiving C:\Users\xxxxxxx\.jenkins\workspace\JenkinsDemo\target\JenkinsDemo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to JenkinsDemo/JenkinsDemo/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/JenkinsDemo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar channel stopped [JenkinsDemo] $ cmd /c call C:\Users\xxxxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\jenkins13221465416928573076.bat

C:\Users\xxxxxxx\.jenkins\workspace\JenkinsDemo>javac EnviarPruebaDeIngles.java  error: file not found: EnviarPruebaDeIngles.java Usage: javac <options> <source files> use
--help for a list of possible options

C:\Users\xxxxxxx\.jenkins\workspace\JenkinsDemo>java EnviarPruebaDeIngles  Error: Could not find or load main class EnviarPruebaDeIngles Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: EnviarPruebaDeIngles

C:\Users\xxxxxxx\.jenkins\workspace\JenkinsDemo>exit 1  Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure Finished: FAILURE
```

Project configuration is:

[image: Configuration part 1]

[image: Configuration part 2]

[image: Configuration part 3]

Our eclipse with selenium project tree, our intention is to execute like the main classes which are going to be located at com.jenkins.demo

[image: Eclipse sample project tree]

Comment: Please never post images of text. They are not searchable, we cannot copy-paste... Always copy-paste the text and format it properly.
Your problem could be a cd problem: https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/91-find-the-current-directory-in-java

Comment: Code tags for that please.

Comment: Edited with code tags

Comment: That's wrong. Try making a log file from what you posted and you'll see why